# Redis clear understanding of the master + replica + sentinel and a standard cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I came across multiple things:

1. Redis `cluster` with multiple master and their corresponding replica(s).
2. Redis `master + replicas` with sentinels.

As per https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial a replica could be promoted to be the next master in case the original master fails. If this is so, why is the Sentinel process needed?

I need clarification on the cluster, cluster with Sentinel.

Are replicas and slaves absolutely the same in the context of Redis?

Answer (score 2):

Redis Sentinel is used for standalone deployed Redis instances.

Redis Cluster does failover by nodes in the cluster. It does not need the help of Redis Sentinel.

In a word, you don't need Redis Sentinel when deploying Redis Cluster.

Comment: Not true! Check the section `Configuring Sentinel` at this Redis doc https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

There are 2 masters mentioned in the config. Of course, there could be more also.

Comment: Those masters are independent standalone-deployed masters. It has nothing to do with Redis Cluster. Redis Sentinel can monitor more than one standalone-deployed masters, of course.